# Is it possible to play against a friend (by random selection) in Ranked Mode?

Tags: hearthstone

The shortest question I ever asked:

Is it possible that a friend from my friends list is selected by random as an opponent in ranked mode? Or are friends avoided in the selection? Does it make a difference, whether the friend or me is invisible or not?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**There is no sure way to face a pre-determined opponent in ranked mode. That's the simple answer.**

However, it is not *impossible* to do so, just generally quite unlikely. There are more players at lower ranks than at higher ranks, so it is less likely to happen at low ranks and likelihood increases at higher ranks.

Anecdotally, I have accomplished this in Arena mode once. My brother (RealID friend on Battle.net) and I had both drafted arena decks. We would time our entry in the queue to be as close as possible. After a few tries, we actually did get matched against each other, but weren't able to do so again. It really just comes down to a bit of timing and a lot of luck.

Comment: People snipe streamers in both Arena and ranked all the time. Queueing up at the same time (at a similar rank, or with similar win/loss stats for Arena) actually gives you a fair shot at intercepting someone.

Comment: Yup it's is certainly possible. However I'm sure it fails more times than it succeeds, but you never hear about the times it didn't work.

Answer (score 13):

You can play against your friends in Ranked in hearthstone - this is shown with streamers play people on their friends list and end up chatting over the Battle.net chat during the game.

However, when you're not in legend/near legend, it's much harder to get paired vs a friend, as there are more people in that band.

Comment: You can, but not on purpose.

Comment: I assumed that was implied by the "by random" in the OP

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible just very very rare i battled my friend in ranked it is almost impossible that that happens but it is still possible